# How do I install wireless drivers for Ralink RT5370 offline?

Tags: wireless

little problem i want to transfer from my windows to ubuntu because its amazing but my wireless usb isnt picked up on ubuntu so its completely offline and i dont know how to download or transfer the driver for it over to ubuntu the computer calls the wireless 802.11n wireless LAN card although on the ralink website that doesnt come up but i think its a RT5370 which i can download on my windows computer but i cant transfer it over to ubuntu via memory stick etc so yeah any help would be appreciated kind of dont want to be forever doomed in windows:D

Comment: Please run `lsusb` and post the output here, so we can determine what kind of WiFi hardware your machine has.

Answer (score 3):

You are using **RT5370** USB device.
Download the driver from [here](http://www.mediatek.com/en/downloads1/downloads/rt8070-rt3070-rt3370-rt3572-rt5370-rt5372-rt5572-usb-usb/).

> Give you Name & E-mail address and press **Accept**.

I assume you download it in **Downloads** folder.

Now open a terminal by pressing **Ctrl+alt+t** and type...

```
cd ~/Downloads
unzip Realtek_RTS5229_Linux_Driver_v1.07.zip
```

it will unzip the arcive in same folder.

```
cd Realtek*
```

There is a tar.bz2 type file.. untar it by typing

```
tar jxvf rts*
cd rts*
```

Now the installation part.

UPDATE : I forgot to mention, you need some dependent package to install `sudo apt-get install build-essential` to solve this.

```
make    
make install    
sudo -s    
depmod    
reboot
```

Done. Hope it helps.

Comment: Not going to work unless he gets `build-essential` and the kernel headers...

Comment: Really sorry, I forgot to mention that. I tried this in my machine which have this package installed. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: The linked website doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Fixed URL http://www.mediatek.com/en/downloads1/downloads/rt8070-rt3070-rt3370-rt3572-rt5370-rt5372-rt5572-usb-usb/

Comment: Hard link to the driver: http://cdn-cw.mediatek.com/Downloads/linux/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022.tar.bz2

Comment: `Realtek_RTS5229_Linux_Driver_v1.07.zip` (the file mentioned in the answer) is a driver for realtek cardreader not for the wifi device in question

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried disabling the power management of your wlan0 device? This did the magic for my €15,- brandless wireless-n usb adapter that has the Ralink 5370 chipset in it. I let (X)ubuntu 12.04 load the pre-built rt2800usb kernel module that seems to work very well with this device. No need to download anything.

You can check the status of the adapter's power management;

```
iwconfig
```

If it is returning a line that says "Power Management:on", than you can turn it off like this;

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

To make this persistant every time you boot, make a small script that contains the line above;

```
sudo touch /etc/pm/power.d/wireless
```

Now make the file executable;

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/pm/power.d/wireless
```

Now insert the lines in the "wireless" file;

```
sudo cat > /etc/pm/power.d/wireless
#!/bin/sh
/sbin/iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

Press "ENTER" and press "Ctrl+D".

Now reboot the computer and check whether power management of the wlan0 adapter is really off;

```
iwconfig wlan0
```

Good luck!

Comment: Tried that but "iwconfig" does not display any wireless adapter at all. Probably I'll have to go with Kaktarua answer (actually i's a bit weird that to get internet connection you need... internet connection)